# C# Add Up Results of Async Methods When All Finished

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have an async method that gets a `List<long>` of component ids for a car id. I want to get component ids for several hundred cars asynchronously, so I wrote the method below. My goal is to actually add up the results of all `GetAllComponentIdsForCar` tasks, and return them from the method below.

```
public async Task<List<long>> GetListOfComponentIds(List<long> carIds)
{
    List<Task> tasksList = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var carId in carIds)
    {
        Task<List<long>> getComponentIds = GetAllComponentIdsForCar(carId);
        tasksList.Add(getComponentIds);
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasksList);

   //List<long> sumOfAllTaskResults...or array...or something
}
```

How do I accomplish this?

Note - I am looking for something similar to angular's [q.all](http://www.martin-brennan.com/using-q-all-to-resolve-multiple-promises/) which simply returns an array of all the task(/promise) results when finished.

I have managed to get results from async tasks in C# before, but that involved making an array the length of expected tasks and that just seems like a horrible way to do it.

I did try reading Microsoft's documentation and questions here, but all I see are arguments about WaitAll vs WhenAll.

Edit:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you changed the declaration of `taskList` to use the generic version of `Task`, `Task<T>` that represents a future value of type `T`...

```
List<Task<List<long>>> taskList
```

now the task's result is of type `List<long>` rather than `void`, and compiler type inference will switch you to a different overload of `Task.WhenAll`, [`Task.WhenAll<TResult>(Task<TResult> tasks)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194766(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Creates a task that will complete when all of the Task objects in an enumerable collection have completed
>
> [...]
>
> The `Task<TResult>.Result` property of the returned task will be set to an array containing all of the results of the supplied tasks in the same order as they were provided (e.g. if the input tasks array contained `t1, t2, t3`, the output task's `Task<TResult>.Result` property will return an `TResult[]` where `arr[0] == t1.Result, arr[1] == t2.Result`, and `arr[2] == t3.Result`).

so, as the type of `Task` is `List<long>`, the following statement is how you'd access the collated result array:

```
List<Long>[] resultLists = await Task.WhenAll(tasksList);
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the reply, but it seems to be returning void (see screenshot in q).

Comment: That was my mistake. Thank you very much.